# Android Appium : Test multiple conditions first before to declare that test is failed

Tags: android, testing, appium, ads

Scenario : I have different types of ads coming . One can be clicked on a button and other can be clicked on the whole ad. 
I have to test when an ad comes , the first test by clicking on the button , if it doesn't work , click on the other type. In appium , in the first if condition if it doesn't find element it will fail the test.
      How can I test multiple conditions before it declares it failed.

Answer (score 1):

There're many ways of doing it. In Python I would go with something' like:

```
    locators = ['.someClass', '#someID']
    for locator in locators:
        el = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(locator)
        if len(el) == 1:
            break
        elif len(el) == 0:
            el = None
        else:
            self.fail('multiple elements: %s found: %d' % locator, len(el))
    self.assertIsNotNone(el, '> 1 matches found on page: %s' % locator)
    el.click()
```

Basically if the locator is not found on the page, then we set el as None and try out another locator. 
If a locator ( in your case let's say button )is found than the method break. If locators found > 1, then it fails.
You must define unique locators for this function to work.

Comment: I was looking for Java. The most efficient method I am using for now is nested try catch method. That helps.